# accessing objects stored in dictionary as values using django templatetag outputs only its string representation; not original object

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary, django-templates

in views.py

I am building a dictionary with strings (A1, A2, A3....C10) as keys and database objects  as values.

```
itemsByPosition = {}
for storage_instance in StorageInstance.objects.all():
    itemsByPosition[storage_instance.cell] = storage_instance
```

in template,

I would like to display the different fields from objects.
An isolated, hardcoded example is (In reality I use loops to print entire dictionary):

```
{{ itemsByPosition|hash:'A2' }}
```

in templatetags.py

```
def hash(h,key):
    if key in h:
        return h[key]
    else:
       return None

register.filter(hash)
```

However, template tag 'hash' returns the string representation of model (eg: "Stabi00052") not the entire object. I want to be able to access various attributes of this object in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access dictionary values directly without a custom filter if the key is a string without spaces or punctuation other than underscores ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups))

```
{{ itemsByPosition.A2.attribute }}
```

Comment: it works great. thanks lain. However, in the current code I'm constructing variable 'position' (holds 'A2') by concatenating 'A' and '2' (using template tags). In that case {{ itemsByPosition.position.attribute }} is not working as expected

Comment: {% with letter|addstr:number as pos %}
                {{ pos }}
                {{ itemsByPosition.pos }}                                                                     {% endwith %}